# context must be a dict rather than module

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

When I am filtering for my search bar I am getting this error. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here

Watching this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llbtoQTt4qw&t=3399s

**views.py**

```
class pplList(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
        model = People
        context_object_name = 'people'
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            search_input = self.get.GET.get('search-area') or ''
            if search_input:
                context['people'] = context['people'].filter(name__icontains=search_input)
            return context
```

**people_list.html**

```
{%if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>{{request.user}}</p>
    <a href="{% url 'logout' %}">Logout</a>
{% else %}
    <a href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
{% endif %}

<hr>
<h1>Interviewee Dashboard {{color}}</h1>


<a href="{% url 'pplCre' %}"> Add Candidates</a>
<form method="get">
    <input type = 'text' name = 'search-are'>
    <input type = 'submit' value = 'Search'>

</form>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th> Item</th>
        <th> </th>

    </tr>
    {% for people in people %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{people.name}}</td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'pplDet' people.id %}">View</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'pplUpd' people.id %}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a href="{% url 'pplDel' people.id %}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    {% empty %}
    <h3>No items in list</h3>
    {% endfor %}
</table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some minor mistakes such as it should be `self.request.GET.get('search-area')`, also you haven't called the `super()` method, so try this view:

```py
class pplList(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = People
    context_object_name = 'people_list'
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context=super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        search_input = self.request.GET.get('search-area', False)
        if search_input:  
           context['people']= People.objects.filter(name__icontains=search_input)
        return context
```

In the Html, the field name `search-are` and you are accessing in the view as `self.request.GET.get('serach-area', False) kindly change its name to` search-area` in the input tag of Html.

Also, class based views are generally written in PascalCase as they are classes of Python and requires their name to be written as model name as prefix and actual view name as suffix, so it should be `PeopleListView`.

Comment: It fixed the error but the searched item doesn't show up

Comment: still in the page wit all the people

Comment: @Vignesh Kindly see in the template you have `search-are` field not `search_area` so change it name in template correctly.

Comment: @Vignesh You need to change it to `sesrch-area` in input tag of html so that the correct searched items of queryset go to the template.